# Counting names that have different IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I wrote a code that is supposed to count me the names that are found multiple times in my column

Here is what each column represents:

```
col1 = Ids (float, null)
col2 = names (nvarchar(255), null)
col3 = region (nvarchar(255), null)
col4 = end_date (datetime, null)
```

Each table has col2, that is how I'm able to link them.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.col1, T2.col2, T2.col3, col4
FROM tab1 AS T
INNER JOIN tab2 AS T2 ON T.col2=T2.col2
WHERE col2 IN 
    (SELECT [col2] FROM [tab1] GROUP BY [col2] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND T.col4 IS NULL
ORDER BY T.col2 ASC
```

Basically, I almost get the desired result but I am missing something in my code. I only want the values in col2 that contain the same name so that I can count them and isolate them. I tried to use the **COUNT** function in my **SELECT** statement, without getting the expected result. I'm unsure, but I believe it might be the data type that is messing up the count possibly.

**Here is a sample of the current results I'm getting:**

```
col1        col2    col3    col4
1222222222  Bus1    NY      NULL
1333333333  Bus2    NY      NULL
1444444444  Bus3    NY      NULL
1555555555  Bus4    NY      NULL
1666666666  Bus4    NY      NULL
1777777777  Bus5    NY      NULL
```

**Here is what I'm expecting and hope to achieve:**

```
col1        col2    col3    col4
1555555555  Bus4    NY      NULL
1666666666  Bus4    NY      NULL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: What is tab2? How is it involved in this case?

Comment: *I almost get the desired result* no way you get any result as it is not syntactically correct.

Comment: I have updated my question and added some details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for to do an inner join of the table itself.

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4
FROM test a
INNER JOIN test b ON a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE a.col1 <> b.col1
```

I have tested it here and it returns what you want:
Have a look : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdb4df/37

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `col1` is unique you can use EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tab1 t
where exists (
  select 1 from tab1
  where col1 <> t.col1 and col2 = t.col2
)
```